# How do I create an isolate scope of the directive's module name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have a directive called `contenteditable` with an isolate scope called `post: "&"`

### **Question:**

**How can I replace the isolated scope called Post with the default contenteditable directive.**

```
angular.module('t23App').
directive("contenteditable", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            post: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            console.log(contenteditable)
            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
            }

            ngModel.$render = function() {
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
            };

            element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

Therefore:
What currently looks like this

```
<div contenteditable post="dosomething()"> Click this</div>
```

In the end the html will look like :

```
<div contenteditable="dosomething()"> Click this</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name of the directive in the scope:

```
scope: {
  contenteditable: "&"
}
```

Comment: ugh really? i feel dumb